# PivotViewer Module for Drupal

Tags: silverlight, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7

Does anybody have any experience with this module?  I am trying to load a collection but have not had any success getting it to load correctly.  I am on Windows Azure, deploying Drupal 7 from Windows Azure Companion.

I suspect that I am not telling my cxml file the proper location of images.  All I get is the blue spinning Silverlight wheel.